# Default selection of country by a 3rd party JS

Tags: javascript

I have one query:

Currently user need to select one country then the states of that country are coming in state field automatically. But I want `united state` selected by default with its states in the state field. How can I do this: Below is my code.....what parameters to pass

```
ll(document).ready(function() {
ll("#country").change(function(){
    ChangeCountryAndStateLabel({
       'obj'       : this,
       'targetObj' : '#state_cus1',
       'sel'       : '',
       'id'        : 'fields_state'
    },{
       'obj'       : this,
       'targetObj' : '#fields_state_region',
       'template'  : '<LABEL>'
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like;

**HTML:**

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="united-states">united states</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").val("united-states");
})
```

You can use this after your code. Only this part:

```
$("#select").val("united-states");
```

See working fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/3Dkfe/**

Comment: Thanks Hüseyin BABAL,

Comment: Thanks Hüseyin BABAL,  But in my code the states are coming automatically when page is loaded or when country is changed. so by default state is coming blank ..you can see link here : http://dev2.yiva.com/daily-balance-qualify/ .. and see the form at the bottom of page... i want that default should be United state and itz states in state field.

Comment: You will use my code in your `change` event. When you select country, your states will be loaded and my code will work

Comment: Your code is not working in my case .. Please see the link which i have given to you ... Check in firbug ... If you are not understanding then please forword this to other expert .. Itz urgent for me